# How to Fetch data from three associated tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a newbie to programming and SQL.In my Rails app, I have tables called users, listings and reservations.A user has_many listings and reservations.A listing has_many reservations and belongs_to a user, and reservation belongs_to listing and user.

schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",
    t.string   "fullname",   
    t.string   "phone_number"
    end  

 create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "vehicle_type",   
    t.string   "listing_name" ,            
    t.string   "make",                         
    t.string   "model",                        
    t.string   "year", 
    t.integer  "daily_rent",
    t.integer  "user_id"   
end

create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",  
     t.integer  "total",
     t.integer  "listing_id"
 end



mysql schema:

     desc users;
  id                           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 email     | varchar(255)
 fullname    | varchar(255)
 phone_number   | varchar(255) 

 desc listings;

  id                           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
  vehicle_type                 | varchar(255)
  make                         | varchar(255)
  model                        | varchar(255)
  year                         | varchar(255) 
  listing_name                 | varchar(255)
  daily_rent                   | int(11)      |
  user_id                      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |

   desc reservations;
   | id                     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   user_id                  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |   
   total                    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       
   listing_id               | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
```

I want  a query to fetch from the reservations with the following details

```
 RESERVATIONS # | LISTING OWNER NAME  | LISTING OWNER EMAIL | LISTING OWNER PHONE | GUEST NAME | GUEST EMAIL | CLASS OF LISTING | YEAR OF LISTING | NIGHTLY RENTAL RATE OF LISTING| TOTAL RENTAL AMOUNT
```

As Listing Owner and Guest, both are users
All I could up with a simple SQL query to fetch all the reservation details with the guest email and phone along with listing details of the corresponding reservation

my query :

```
 select r.id , u.email, u.fullname ,l.listing_name,l.year,l.daily_rent,r.total  from reservations r , users u ,listings l where u.id = r.user_id and l.id = r.listing_id;
```

**1)** I am **unable** to extract the LISTING OWNER NAME | OWNER EMAIL | OWNER PHONE but I am **able** to get Guest NAME | GUEST EMAIL | GUEST PHONE.
How to fetch the LISTING OWNER details ??

**2)** How to write the whole query using joins or any other SQL clauses (i am not a fan of u.email, u.fullname,l.year..etc approach)

**3)** Is it possible to fetch all the above data from a single query ??

please let me know if you need additional details.

Any Help is highly Appreciated.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: did you get your answer? I've pushed an answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use inner join query for three associated tables like below:

```
SELECT r.id, u.email, u.fullname, l.listing_name, l.year, l.daily_rent, r.total
FROM users u INNER JOIN listings l ON u.id = l.user_id INNER JOIN 
reservations r ON l.id = r.listing_id and l.user_id = r.user_id
```

hopefully it will work fine. If you need any further assistance, I'll modify the query.

Comment: @suresh try to implement this and let me know your thought

Comment: you can see my query from the question

"select r.id , u.email, u.fullname ,l.listing_name,l.year,l.daily_rent,r.total  from reservations r , users u ,listings l where u.id = r.user_id and l.id = r.listing_id;"

you are also fetching the same 
(r.id , u.email, u.fullname ,l.listing_name,l.year,l.daily_rent,r.total).But I want listing owner info.our query is fetching reservation guest info.

Comment: @suresh Can you send some sample data like owner and guest info in the table view. I'll be availabe with laptop after half an hour.